# Tomcat7 not staring completely

Tags: tomcat7

I've installed tomcat7 as best I can via apt-get (after removing a perfectly working tomcat6) on ubuntu running on a vmware image.  I've added a user with several manager roles in tomcat-users.xml and have modified the Connector's port from 8080 to 80.

When I start tomcat with "sudo service start tomcat7" I get the message:

```
 * Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat7
```

but my browser doesn't get any response from either localhost:80 or localhost:8080.  Furthermore,

```
 netstat | grep 80
```

doesn't show either port 80 or port 8080 in use.

I can find no trace of any log files in or around the catalina directory referred to by both $CATALINA_HOME and $CATALINA_BASE.

Should I be looking somewhere else for the logs?  Any other recommendations?

Comment: Can you paste your `tomcat-users.xml` to pastebin.ubuntu.com and post the link to your question?

Comment: Following command should show you whom listening on which port: `netstat -plnt` What do you see when executing? Is it actually running? `sudo service tomcat status` Check logs folder for clues: `${catalina.base}/logs`

Answer (score 0):

You mention VMware, so I presume that this is on a VM? A delay in Tomcat starting could be due to a shortage of entropy, as described in [bug 1269073](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomcat7/+bug/1269073).

This should be fixed in Trusty cloud images with the [new pollinate system](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2014/02/random-seeds-in-ubuntu-1404-lts-cloud.html). If you aren't using official Ubuntu cloud images, try installing `pollinate` by hand.

(This may not be the answer in your specific case, but it is one avenue to investigate for anybody with this kind of issue)